# Jquery Mobile Panel styling issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

Hello there i am using the code bellow to load a sliding panel to my page and load the `<li>` content inside of it from an external html file. The problem is that when i am loading the data from external html file the styling doesn't applying.
If i move the code inside my primary html file it works fine.
In external html file i also loaded the .css files

Here is my full working code and bellow i will post and what i am trying to do.

```
//Loading the jquery css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">

//Loading jquery and jquery mobile
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

//Before open i am loading the external file with content
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on("pagecreate", "#panel-responsive-page1", function () {
    $( "#nav-panelz" ).on( "panelbeforeopen", function( event, ui ) {
      $("#loadexternal").load("external.php");
      alert('opened');
    });
  });
</script>
```

And inside my body

```
<div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos ui-responsive-panel" id="panel-responsive-page1" data-title="Panel responsive page"> <!-- STARTS data-role="page" -->

<div data-role="panel" data-display="push" data-theme="b" id="nav-panelz" class="mypanel" style="z-index:250000;">

<ul data-role="listview" id="loadexternal">

//at this was the code bellow and works great
<li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close" style="color:#09F;">Close menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Menu one</a></li>
<li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Menu two</a></li>
</ul>

</div>


</div> <!-- ENDS data-role="page" -->
```

If i remove the two lines and put it in my external.php file the style is not apply.

```
<li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Menu one</a></li>
<li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Menu two</a></li>
```

Thank you all!

Screenshots bellow will help you what i mean:

[image]

And from external file:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean the styles are not applied? CSS isn't dependent upon jQuery. Can you show screenshots?

Comment: Doesn't look like the problem is about styles. Is the plugin even working? Does the panel slide?

Comment: @isherwood It's just a sample how it looks like when i have the <li> inside the single html and the other when i am loading the <li> content from external file.. It's seems that css doensn't apply at the second image.. The panel slides correct.

Comment: Is there anything else in `external.php`? What does the rendered HTML look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You need to enhance elements that are dynamically injected. To enhance/initialize all items in spite of their *type*, you need to call `.enhanceWithin()` on parent div.</strike>

Although `.enhanceWithin()` should do the job, however, it looks like it failed here. Anyway, all you need to *re-enhance* listview widget by calling `.listview("refresh");` after successfully loading external elements.

```
$( "#nav-panelz" ).on( "panelbeforeopen", function( event, ui ) {
  $("#loadexternal").load("external.php", function () {
     $("#loadexternal").listview("refresh");
  });
});
```

Comment: it didn't work. Even if i was including the .css inside the external file.

Comment: @IreneT. you dont need to add CSS in that external file. Can you post a sample of that file's content? Edit: is that panel external? is that panel inside page `#panel-responsive-page1`?

Comment: @IreneT. remove `<link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">` you dont need it.

Comment: check this one that i have the <li> inside the current html http://www.celebrityposted.com/jquerymobile/index2.html

Comment: @IreneT. another option add this inside external.php (between elements) `<script>$(function () { $( "#nav-panelz" ).enhanceWithin();   });</script>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49700/discussion-between-irene-t-and-omar)